# Double Click not firing when testing a React 0.5.0 webpage with Intern

Tags: reactjs, intern

I'm trying to use Intern to create functional tests for a React (0.12.2) webpage.  I ran into an issue while trying to test functionality which is triggered by the `dblclick` event.  The event fires normally when I am manually testing the webpage but it does not fire in my Intern tests.

<s>Also, not sure if this information matters, but in the environment I am testing in (Dartium), `brokenMouseEvents` is `true` and `brokenDoubleClick` is `false`.  I am using Selenium for my WebDriver server (v2.43.1, with Core v2.43.1. Built from revision 5163bce).</s>

I am testing on SauceLabs.  Here is my error log: https://github.com/danielbank/testDoubleClick/blob/master/saucelabs_results.log

GitHub Repo:

https://github.com/danielbank/testDoubleClick

React Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Doubleclick</title>
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.12.2/react.js"></script>
<script>
    var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
        render : function() {
            return React.DOM.div({},[
                React.DOM.button({'id': 'foo', 'onDoubleClick': function() {
                    React.renderComponent(React.DOM.p({'id': 'double-click-fired'},['Double Click Fired']), document.body);
                }}, ['Double Click Me']),
                React.DOM.button({'id': 'bar', 'onClick': function() {
                    React.renderComponent(React.DOM.p({'id': 'click-fired'},['Click Fired']), document.body);
                }}, ['Click Me'])
            ]);
        }
    });
    React.renderComponent(
            HelloWorld({}),
            document.body
    );
</script>
</html>
```

Intern Tests:

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'require'
], function (registerSuite, assert) {
    registerSuite({
        name: 'test doubleclick functionality',
        'test singleclick': function () {
            return this.remote.get('http://localhost:8010/web/test_doubleclick.html')
                .findById('bar')
                .sleep(2000)
                .click()
                .end()
                .sleep(2000)
                .findById('click-fired')
                .getVisibleText()
                .then(function(text) {
                    assert.equal(text, 'Click Fired');
                });
        },
        'test doubleclick': function () {
            return this.remote.get('http://localhost:8010/web/test_doubleclick.html')
                .findById('foo')
                .sleep(2000)
                .doubleClick()
                .end()
                .sleep(2000)
                .findById('double-click-fired')
                .getVisibleText()
                .then(function(text) {
                    assert.equal(text, 'Double Click Fired');
                });
        }
    });
});
```

Intern Configuration:

```
define({
    proxyPort: 9000,

    proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',

    capabilities: {
        'selenium-version': '2.44.0'
    },

    environments: [
        { browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '11', platform: 'Windows 8.1' },
        { browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '10', platform: 'Windows 8' },
        { browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '9', platform: 'Windows 7' },
        { browserName: 'firefox', version: '28', platform: [ 'OS X 10.9', 'Windows 7', 'Linux' ] },
        { browserName: 'chrome', version: '34', platform: [ 'OS X 10.9', 'Windows 7', 'Linux' ] },
        { browserName: 'safari', version: '6', platform: 'OS X 10.8' },
        { browserName: 'safari', version: '7', platform: 'OS X 10.9' }
    ],

    maxConcurrency: 3,

    tunnel: 'SauceLabsTunnel',

    tunnelOptions: {
        username: '<username>',
        accessKey: '<accessKey>'
    },

    useLoader: {
        'host-node': 'dojo/dojo',
        'host-browser': 'node_modules/dojo/dojo.js'
    },

    reporters: ['pretty'],

    functionalSuites: [ 'tests/functional/index' ],

    excludeInstrumentation: /^(?:tests|node_modules)\//
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The only time that `brokenMouseEvents` is true is when the remote browser is identified as being Safari. Obviously this should not be the case with any Chromium build. Can you show your Intern configuration and also share what WebDriver server you are using?

Comment: @CSnover I updated this question with a link to a GitHub repo with my problem.  Hopefully that makes this question easier to reproduce.  Please let me know if it is still unclear.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this issue. I'm not sure if the problem is specific to just React components, but the solution is to precede the `doubleClick()` with a `click()`:

`'test singleclick': function () {
    return this.remote.get('http://localhost:8010/web/test_doubleclick.html')
        .findById('bar')
        .sleep(2000)
        .click()
        .doubleClick()
        .end()
        .sleep(2000)
        .findById('click-fired')
        .getVisibleText()
        .then(function(text) {
            assert.equal(text, 'Click Fired');
        });
}`

The intern.js documentation for [`doubleClick`](http://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Command.html#doubleClick) indicates that it:

> Double-clicks the primary mouse button.

This does not seem to be the case. There seems to either be a bug in intern or a bug in the documentation.